# How can I make cdrecord have UNINTERRUPTED use of system resources?

Tags: process-management, burning

I'd like to burn thirty mp3 songs to a CD-R, using say cdrecord. But I'd like to
use my laptop for other things at the same time (such as using the Kate editor
and the Internet).

However, I've read that if the laser is writing to the CD, and the process is
interrupted, the writing is spoiled.

**My Question:**

So how can I make cdrecord and the CD recorder have uninterrupted use of system
resources, while still allowing me to do other things on the system?

Comment: This was a concern in the early days of CD burning, but it hasn’t been an issue in practice for many years.

Comment: Unless you're using a machine stolen from a computer museum, it's a total non-issue. And íirc cdrecord used to raise its priority itself -- you didn't have to do anything.

Comment: Unless your CD writer is very old, it is likely to have a *buffer underrun protection* feature that allows the writer to stop and restart writing as needed. Just make sure your `cdrecord` configuration enables it if you feel you need added insurance. Between the `cdrecord` auto-raising its priority and the general increase of CPU and I/O capacity since the first CD writers were introduced, you'll have to put some significant strain to the system to cause an underrun in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The common answer to this is concern is to "nice" the `cdrecord` process. That tells the kernel "give this process here a higher (or lower) priority for resources than normal" - how much higher (or lower) depends on the nice value you give it. From `man nice`:

```
SYNOPSIS
   nice [OPTION] [COMMAND [ARG]...]

DESCRIPTION
   Run  COMMAND  with an adjusted niceness, which affects process schedul‐
   ing.  With no COMMAND, print the  current  niceness.   Niceness  values
   range  from  -20 (most favorable to the process) to 19 (least favorable
   to the process).
```

If your `cdrecord` process is already running, you can use the `renice` command to adjust it's nice value in the same way - see `man renice` for details.

Comment: Sorry, your answer is not correct. If you use `nice` or `renice`, you make things worse and always lower the priority.

Comment: While the answer doesn't give any specific example, isn't it possible (as root) to use nice or renice to increase the priority?

Comment: How do you like to **increase** the priority with a program that only knows about priorities that are lower than what `cdrecord` selects on it's own?

Comment: As root, you can increase the priority. That's what the negative numbers are for. The 'default' priority is 0, using a negative number to `nice` or `renice` will increase the priority.

Comment: From `man renice`:

       "The superuser may alter the priority of any process and set the  prior‐
       ity  to  any  value  in the range -20 to 19.  Useful priorities are: 19
       (the affected processes will run only when nothing else in  the  system
       wants  to), 0 (the ``base'' scheduling priority), anything negative (to
       make things go very fast)."

Comment: @schily If there's more information behind your comment that would help John improve their answer, please don't hold back! Saying "this is wrong, you'll make it worse" doesn't give them an opportunity to fix their answer.

Comment: @JeffSchaller The informaton fom my answer combined with the comment from above gives all available basic information. If John likes more informaton, he could  ask a related question that is specific enough. Cdrecord by default uses a priority that is higher than the most priorized kernel process.

Comment: @John and then there are also the *real-time* priorities which are "faster" than -20 and that `nice` doesn't know about.

Answer (score 1):

If `cdrecord` is installed correctly or called by root as needed, `cdrecord` always puts itself into the highest real time priority and locks memory.

This gives `cdrecord` the best conditions for writing.

You unfortunately did not mention the operating system, so I can only give general advise.

- `cdrecord` always needs special system privileges in order to be able to send any SCSI command to any SCSI device.
- To achieve the special system privileges on a vanilla UNIX system, you install `cdrecord` suid root to give it all available privileges.
- On Solaris you grant exactly the needed fine grained privileges to `cdrecord` by making the apropriate entries in the `pfexec` database in `/etc/security`.
- On a recent Linux, you can grant the apropriate fine grained capabilities using the `setcap` command.

If you e.g. run an unprivileged cdrecord on Linux, you get the following result:

```
cdrecord -scanbus
Cdrecord-ProDVD-ProBD-Clone 3.02a10 2021/07/23 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) Copyright (C) 1995-2019 Joerg Schilling
cdrecord: Insufficient 'file read' privileges. You will not be able to open all needed devices.
cdrecord: Insufficient 'file write' privileges. You will not be able to open all needed devices.
cdrecord: Insufficient 'device' privileges. You may not be able to send all needed SCSI commands, this my cause various unexplainable problems.
cdrecord: Insufficient 'memlock' privileges. You may get buffer underruns.
cdrecord: Insufficient 'priocntl' privileges. You may get buffer underruns.
cdrecord: Insufficient 'network' privileges. You will not be able to do remote SCSI.
cdrecord: Keine Berechtigung. Cannot open '/dev/sg0'. Cannot open or use SCSI driver.
cdrecord: For possible targets try 'cdrecord -scanbus'. Make sure you are root.
cdrecord: For possible transport specifiers try 'cdrecord dev=help'.
```

which reminds you to run cdrecord with the needed privileges.

So just use a recent `cdrecord` and it will do the right things for you.